# How to notate different composers in different sections of a piece?

Tags: composition, transcription

I'm arranging a medley of songs with different composers and am stuck on how to notate the composers. I've thought of listing the composers with their songs as they appear in the music (I'm already writing the song name above the staff when the songs change) or listing the composers in order of appearance, but the former is very cumbersome and the latter is somewhat vague. Is there any established method of citing composers in medleys?

Note: All the songs in question are in the public domain, but I'd still like to give credit.

Comment: Just an opinion, but it seems to me that a score should have readability as its main concern, so I would not insert written information not relevant to the execution. The song title, perhaps abreviated, can be a useful visual cue for the performer, but not the composer. A list of credits appended to the score seems to me a more practical approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the name of the composer (perhaps in a smaller font or in parenthesis) under the name of the song. Maybe right justified so as not to dominate.